# How do I URl encode something in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, url, node.js

I want to URL encode this:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

Do I have to download a module for this? I already have the request module.

Comment: Indeed, this is a slippy road and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Are you trying to put SQL statement in your url??? be careful of the [SQL Injection Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! It's generally a bad idea to expose SQL to the users, it's really dangerous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: looks like an FQL-query.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Doesn't Stack Exchange do this?  If I understand this, it uses permissions at the DBMS to keep anything bad from happening.

Comment: @Demi: No? How would that work. DBMS permissions are not sufficiently fine-grained, even if every single SO user got their own DB account. Tell me where on SO you see SQL queries passed directly? The one exception is data explorer, but that's all read-only views, and it's certainly not put in the URL.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was referring to read-only views.

Comment: @Demi: The answer's still no

Comment: The guy could be building an SQL validation tool, nothing wrong with passing SQL commands in an example like that. Too much focus on not answering the question neither giving good advice (the most upvoted comment doesn't give good advice, only makes fun of the OP)

Answer (score 812, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
encodeURIComponent('select * from table where i()')
```

giving

```
'select%20*%20from%20table%20where%20i()'
```

Comment: To save visitors a search, yes... `decodeURIComponent` is how you _decode_ the encoded URI. You're welcome.

Comment: It helped me query in Bengali language using NodeJS. Thank you!

Answer (score 151):

The built-in module [`querystring`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) is what you're looking for:

```
var querystring = require("querystring");
var result = querystring.stringify({query: "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()"});
console.log(result);
#prints 'query=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me()'
```

Comment: in this case we can only pass a map not a string, so if arg is a string then you will see nothing in result. 

So if you have strings to encode use encodeURIComponent().

Comment: This is better for encoding JSON objects and POST-ing them.

Comment: Not if the string contains ' or " characters

Answer (score 52):

Use the `escape` function of `querystring`. It generates a URL safe string.

```
var escaped_str = require('querystring').escape('Photo on 30-11-12 at 8.09 AM #2.jpg');
console.log(escaped_str);
// prints 'Photo%20on%2030-11-12%20at%208.09%20AM%20%232.jpg'
```

Comment: This definitely appears to be the correct function; `querystring.stringify()` (in Nicolas' answer) seem to return an empty string now.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_escape_str says: "The `querystring.escape()` method is used by `querystring.stringify()` and is generally not expected to be used directly."

Answer (score 32):

Note that URI encoding is good for the query part, it's not good for the domain. The domain gets encoded using punycode. You need a library like [URI.js](https://github.com/garycourt/uri-js) to convert between a URI and IRI (Internationalized Resource Identifier).

This is correct if you plan on using the string later as a query string:

```
> encodeURIComponent("http://examplé.org/rosé?rosé=rosé")
'http%3A%2F%2Fexampl%C3%A9.org%2Fros%C3%A9%3Fros%C3%A9%3Dros%C3%A9'
```

If you don't want ASCII characters like `/`, `:` and `?` to be escaped, use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) instead:

```
> encodeURI("http://examplé.org/rosé?rosé=rosé")
'http://exampl%C3%A9.org/ros%C3%A9?ros%C3%A9=ros%C3%A9'
```

However, for other use-cases, you might need [uri-js](https://github.com/garycourt/uri-js) instead:

```
> var URI = require("uri-js");
undefined
> URI.serialize(URI.parse("http://examplé.org/rosé?rosé=rosé"))
'http://xn--exampl-gva.org/ros%C3%A9?ros%C3%A9=ros%C3%A9'
```

Comment: I don't understand why `xn--` is added in the second example. It will not work as an url or I missed something ?

Comment: Look on second "e" in `http://examplé.org` it is not ASCII character and should be presented as [punnycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

Answer (score 19):

encodeURIComponent(string) will do it:

```
encodeURIComponent("Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--")
//>> "Robert')%3B%20DROP%20TABLE%20Students%3B--"
```

⚠️ Passing SQL around in a query string might not be a good plan though: [see this one](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: We call him little Bobby Tables :-P

Answer (score 1):

##### encodeURI

The [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) method is used to encode a complete URL. This method encodes special characters except `~!$&@#*()=:/,;?+`

##### encodeURIComponent

To encode special characters in URI components, you should use the [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) method. This method is suitable for encoding URL components such as query string parameters and not the complete URL.