# Heroku + Node.js: How to use urls with umlauts?

Tags: url, node.js, heroku

I have got a Node.js application which uses umlauts in some of its urls. When I run node.js locally, everything works fine.

Now I want to deploy this application to Heroku. Running Heroku's foreman locally works fine as well, but once I deploy and try to access any of the umlaut urls, I get an "500 Internal server error".

Does Heroku support umlauts in urls when running Node.js? If so, any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Problem solved (or worked around ;-)), by simply avoiding umlauts.

Answer (score 0):

To use umlauts (or other special characters) you need to ["url-encode" or "percent encode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the characters so they can be used properly in URLs. In your case the umlauts could be substituted with the code `%d6` (see [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout)), but you may be more interested in the javascript function [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), which will let you encode things programatically. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6554045/28037).