# URL component encoding in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, urlencode, url-encoding, percent-encoding

I want to send http request using node.js. I do:

```
http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'www.mainsms.ru',
    path: '/api/mainsms/message/send?project='+project+'&sender='+sender+'&message='+message+'&recipients='+from+'&sign='+sign
    };

    http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
    });
```

When my `path` like this:

```
/api/mainsms/message/send?project=geoMessage&sender=gis&message=tester_response&recipients=79089145***&sign=2c4135e0f84d2c535846db17b1cec3c6
```

Its work. But when `message` parameter contains any spaces for example `tester response` all broke. And in console i see that http use this url:

```
  /api/mainsms/message/send?project=geoMessage&sender=gis&message=tester
```

How to send spaces. Or i just can't use spaces in url?

Comment: You need to do URL encoding.

Comment: @thefourtheeye: Can you give any examples or links to read?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent and http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I URl encode something in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554039/how-do-i-url-encode-something-in-node-js)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [URL component encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
path: '/api/mainsms/message/send?project=' + project + 
'&sender=' + sender + 
'&message=' + message +
'&recipients=' + from + 
'&sign=' + sign
```

has to be changed to

```
path: '/api/mainsms/message/send?project=' + encodeURIComponent(project) +
'&sender=' + encodeURIComponent(sender) +
'&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message) + 
'&recipients='+encodeURIComponent(from) +
'&sign=' + encodeURIComponent(sign)
```

**Note:**

There are two functions available. [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). You need to use `encodeURI` when you have to encode the entire URL and `encodeURIComponent` when the query string parameters have to be encoded, like in this case. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1903116) for extensive explanation.

Comment: Necromancer here ...
This answer is not valid, encodeURIComponent is a window property, so it's only available in browsers, not Node.js (see title).

Comment: @JulienCROUZET Actually `encodeURIComponent` is available in Node.js as well. It is provided by v8. Please check [this](http://ideone.com/q2Ddjp) out.

Comment: It /may/ be available, it is defined in ECMA but has no existance in Node.js doc, so no LTS or other assurances for it. The /Official/ way is the querystring module

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Are you saying I should not suggest functions like Array, String etc just because they are not in Node.js documentation?

Comment: To clarify thefourtheye’s point, it seems odd to consider node’s homegrown querystring module (which has been effectively deprecated by URLSearchParams anyway) to be more "official" than functionality which has been specified by a formal international standard as part of the language itself for nearly two decades :)

Comment: As stupid as it may look, since it's not part of the Node.js documentation, `encodeURIComponent` is the right answer. Use it like it is without any requires/imports

Answer (score 23):

The question is for Node.js. `encodeURIcomponent` is not defined in Node.js. Use the `querystring.escape()` method instead.

```
var qs = require('querystring');
qs.escape(stringToBeEscaped);
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? I believe it should be.

Comment: When the question was originally posted (2013), encodeURIComponent was not available in Node.js. Even in 2016, it was not available in many packaged versions of Node.js, even though it was available in, say, version 6. Question of timing I guess?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the native module [QueryString](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) :

```js
var qs = require('querystring');
console.log(qs.escape('Hello $ é " \' & ='));
// 'Hello%20%24%20%C3%A9%20%22%20\'%20%26%20%3D'
```

This is a native module, so you don't have to `npm install` anything.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR: Use fixedEncodeURI() and fixedEncodeURIComponent()

[**MDN encodeURI() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
>    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
> }
> ```

[**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
>  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>  });
> }
> ```

#### Why to Not Use encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent()

It is really not recommended to use `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`, as they are insufficient to properly handle URI or URL encoding directly.  Just like at this piece...

```
'&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message) +
```

Let's say that the `message` var is set to this: `"Hello, world! (Really hello!)"`.  So what is that evaluated to?

```js
console.log('&message=' + encodeURIComponent("Hello, world! (Really hello!)"));
```

Output:

> `&message=Hello%2C%20world!%20(Really%20hello!)`

That's not right!  Why weren't `(` and `)` encoded?  After all, according to [**RFC3986**](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), Section 2.2: Reserved Characters...

> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"  / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

Parens are a sub-delim, but they are not being escaped by `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()`.