# How to pass URL as parameter with another URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I have this route `/new/:url`. Now, when I make request like `/new/https://www.google.com`, I get `Cannot GET /new/https://www.google.com` as the response. What I expect is to get the string `https://www.google.com`. I read this answer [URL component encoding in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077203/url-component-encoding-in-node-js?noredirect=1&lq=1) about encoding the URL but how will I be able to do so when a `GET` request is made to the route `/new/:url` ? Here is my code for that route

```
app.get('/new/:url',(req,res) => {
  const url = encodeURIComponent(req.params.url);
  console.log(url);
  res.json({
    url
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a try this way with `wildcard` routing, not tested but it should work

```
app.get('/new/*',(req,res) => {
  const url_param = req.params[0];
  const url = req.hostname;
  console.log(url,url_param);
  res.json({
    url
  });
});
```

`req.params[0]` will give you the https://www.google.com portion of http://www.yourapp.com/new/https://www.google.com and 
`req.hostname` will give you the original http://www.yourapp.com/ .

Comment: This works. But I don't understand why my route handler does not works ? This method also does not encode the URL then why it is not treating the `/` in `https://www.google.com` as seperate parts of url and breaking the response.

Comment: This may work but every parameter should be encoded while transporting as url component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to route to an encoded url. In your router callback function you should decode the url component.

```
app.get('/new/:url',(req,res) => {
   const url = decodeURIComponent(req.params.url);
   console.log(url);
   res.json({
     url
   });
 });
```

And the part where you link to this `/new` section should `encodeURIComponent()` the passed url.

The encoded url should look like `/new/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.de`

Frontend Part:

```
const baseUrl = '/new';
const urlParameter = 'http://example.com';
const targetUrl = `${baseUrl}/${encodeUriComponent(urlParameter)}`;
const method = 'GET';

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method,targetUrl);
xhr.onload = () => {

    const jsonCallback = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
}

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Do you use a frontend framework? Since the backend lib is express (i think) the frontend should do the work. Ill edit my answer to provide a non framework example.