# Serialize query parameters to a filename

Tags: node.js, file-io

I'd like to map an API request 1::1 with a file name.

This means, among other things, serializing query params into something safe for a filename, ideally on both Windows and *nix.

If the api request is this:

```
api/eggs/fresh?search=brown&order=asc
```

Then the filename might be:

```
api/eggs/fresh?search=brown&order=asc.json
```

But the `?` char and maybe the `&` are unsafe, so I have to encode them I think.

The serialization must be bi-directionally deterministic. I have to be able to get the data back out. Converting all illegal characters to `_`, for example, wouldn't meet this criteria.

Is the right method `querystring.encode`? This is for encoding URLs but might work if `%` is file system safe. [How do I URl encode something in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554039/how-do-i-url-encode-something-in-node-js)? Or is there something better suited to a file system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm following this process:

1. Get folder + resource name
2. Get Array of params in the request
3. Alphabetize params (so order doesn't matter)
4. Join params with `&` (I think this is safe in modern file systems)
5. Concat `folder/resource` + `__&__` + `paramString` + `.json`

This fails if someone uses `__&__` as part of an actual query, but I think that's unlikely. Not the cleanest solution, I'd love a better one!