# Using non-english languages to get google GeoCode coordinates

Tags: google-maps, excel, geolocation, vba

I'm using this [PAGE](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/06/geocoding-using-vba-google-api.html) to get Google map coordinates. When using English names there is no problem and excel file returns coordinates. But when using Persian (or Arabic) names excel file returns `Request was empty or malformed`.I set language in VBA file but din't fix the problem:

```
Request.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?" _
& "&address=" & Address & "&sensor=false" & "&language=fa", False
```

What should I do?

File: [Excel file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104548452/Geocoding%20Using%20VBA%20%26%20Google%20API.xlsm)

Comment: Came here looking for node.js solution for the same problem. It is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6554045/3678257 TL,DR: `encodeURIComponent(address)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL must be url encoded. So since the other is all ASCII, the `Address` must be url encoded. Try the code after Edit2 from the best answer of this post [How can I URL encode a string in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba) as function `URLEncode()` to do this. This should support all languages.

```
Request.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?" _
& "&address=" & URLEncode(Address) & "&sensor=false" & "&language=fa", False
```

or within the function call

```
... GetCoordinates(URLEncode(Address))
```

I put those two functions into a Module:

```
Function GetCoordinates(Address As String) As String

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'This function returns the latitude and longitude of a given address using the Google Geocoding API.
    'The function uses the "simplest" form of Google Geocoding API (sending only the address parameter),
    'so, optional parameters such as bounds, key, language, region and components are NOT used.
    'In case of multiple results (for example two cities sharing the same name), the function
    'returns the FIRST OCCURRENCE, so be careful in the input address (tip: use the city name and the
    'postal code if they are available).

    'NOTE: As Google points out, the use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a limit of 2500
    'requests per day, so be careful not to exceed this limit.
    'For more info check: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

    'In order to use this function you must enable the XML, v3.0 library from VBA editor:
    'Go to Tools -> References -> check the Microsoft XML, v3.0.

    'Written by:    Christos Samaras
    'Date:          12/06/2014
    'e-mail:        xristos.samaras@gmail.com
    'site:          http://www.myengineeringworld.net
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Declaring the necessary variables. Using 30 at the first two variables because it
    'corresponds to the "Microsoft XML, v3.0" library in VBA (msxml3.dll).
    Dim Request         As New XMLHTTP30
    Dim Results         As New DOMDocument30
    Dim StatusNode      As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim LatitudeNode    As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim LongitudeNode   As IXMLDOMNode

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    'Create the request based on Google Geocoding API. Parameters (from Google page):
    '- Address: The address that you want to geocode.
    '- Sensor: Indicates whether your application used a sensor to determine the user's location.
    'This parameter is no longer required.
    Request.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?" _
    & "&address=" & Address & "&sensor=false", False

    'Send the request to the Google server.
    Request.send

    'Read the results from the request.
    Results.LoadXML Request.responseText

    'Get the status node value.
    Set StatusNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//status")

    'Based on the status node result, proceed accordingly.
    Select Case UCase(StatusNode.Text)

        Case "OK"   'The API request was successful. At least one geocode was returned.

            'Get the latitdue and longitude node values of the first geocode.
            Set LatitudeNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/geometry/location/lat")
            Set LongitudeNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/geometry/location/lng")

            'Return the coordinates as string (latitude, longitude).
            GetCoordinates = LatitudeNode.Text & ", " & LongitudeNode.Text

        Case "ZERO_RESULTS"   'The geocode was successful but returned no results.
            GetCoordinates = "The address probably not exists"

        Case "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" 'The requestor has exceeded the limit of 2500 request/day.
            GetCoordinates = "Requestor has exceeded the server limit"

        Case "REQUEST_DENIED"   'The API did not complete the request.
            GetCoordinates = "Server denied the request"

        Case "INVALID_REQUEST"  'The API request is empty or is malformed.
            GetCoordinates = "Request was empty or malformed"

        Case "UNKNOWN_ERROR"    'Indicates that the request could not be processed due to a server error.
            GetCoordinates = "Unknown error"

        Case Else   'Just in case...
            GetCoordinates = "Error"

    End Select

    'In case of error, release the objects.
errorHandler:
    Set StatusNode = Nothing
    Set LatitudeNode = Nothing
    Set LongitudeNode = Nothing
    Set Results = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing

End Function


Public Function URLEncode( _
   StringVal As String, _
   Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False _
) As String
  Dim bytes() As Byte, b As Byte, i As Integer, space As String

  If SpaceAsPlus Then space = "+" Else space = "%20"

  If Len(StringVal) > 0 Then
    With New ADODB.Stream
      .Mode = adModeReadWrite
      .Type = adTypeText
      .Charset = "UTF-8"
      .Open
      .WriteText StringVal
      .Position = 0
      .Type = adTypeBinary
      .Position = 3 ' skip BOM
      bytes = .Read
    End With

    ReDim result(UBound(bytes)) As String

    For i = UBound(bytes) To 0 Step -1
      b = bytes(i)
      Select Case b
        Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
          result(i) = Chr(b)
        Case 32
          result(i) = space
        Case 0 To 15
          result(i) = "%0" & Hex(b)
        Case Else
          result(i) = "%" & Hex(b)
      End Select
    Next i

    URLEncode = Join(result, "")
  End If
End Function
```

To get those functions to work, I had to include a reference to a recent version of the "Microsoft XML.." and the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" libraries in the VBA project.

Now I have the following Excel sheet:
[image]

Comment: You need the function `URLEncode` from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218181/how-can-i-url-encode-a-string-in-excel-vba. It is not an default function in Excel.

Comment: I did all things you mentioned. it returns `#VALUE!`. Can you edit mentioned excel file and put it here?. I think this edited file help me so much.

Comment: as an example `URLEncode("Good")` or `URLEncode(Good)` returns `#VALUE!`. why?

Comment: `URLEncode("Good")`should work. It works for me. `URLEncode(Good)` will only work if `Good` is a defined name in Excel. If not it will return `#VALUE!`.

Comment: Oh, you have the reference to the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" library? If not, get this via Tools - References - Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects...